# Rails 3 Nested Resource Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-routes

I have a few questions relating to a Transaction object that I'm creating.

Transaction belongs_to Loan and Loan has_many Transactions.

Therefore, I setup a nested route:

```
resources :loans do
  resources :transactions
end
```

My question is: How do I pass the loan value into the Transaction's 'loan_id' field? Is this best done in the controller or as a hidden_field in the form? Does the nested route create an easy way to grab this variable?

I assumed this would be done automatically, but the field is empty when I saved it as-is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you call a specific transaction, the route for a `new` transaction will be

```
loans/:loan_id/transactions/new
```

you could use model association like this: in your `create` action:

```
@transaction = Loan.find(params[:loan_id]).transactions.build
```

that way your new `@transaction` will be already populated with the loan_id

Comment: I just tried this and I got the following message: Couldn't find Loan without an ID. Do you why the :loan_id isn't being recognized?

Comment: make sure you have a loan in the database with the :loan_id you're trying to call. calling find on Loan will raise an exception if the loan with the id = loan_id does not exist - that should only happen if you type the url manually

Comment: The Loan exists and I'm linking to it with <%= link_to 'Lend Now', new_loan_transaction_path(@loan), :class => 'lend_button' %> Is that correct? It's still throwing the error for some reason. Thanks for the added help!

Comment: the link is correct (the action `new`, for a transaction in `@loan`). when is the error thrown? in the `new` or `create` action? what prints if you `puts params[:loan_id]`? is it the `id` of the called loan?

Comment: The error is thrown right after submitting the new Transaction form and it's titled ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TransactionsController#create. So, it's in the create method. There appears to be nothing in the params[:loan_id]. For some reason, I don't think the two are connecting. Is there something I need to add beyond what I have above to the routes perhaps? Thanks again, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: i tried replicating your models, relations and controllers, and for test purposes, all i have in create is `@transaction = Loan.find(params[:loan_id]).transactions.build(params[:transaction])` after which i call `save`. and it works. does running `rake routes` give a route like `new_loan_transaction GET    /loans/:loan_id/transactions/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"transactions"}` ? if the answer is yes, then i'm starting to go out of ideas :)

Comment: Thanks, my friend! It works now! I'm not sure what exactly caused it to work, because I made multiple changes at once, but it works! I really appreciate all of the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a `before_filter` to your controller and having it call a private method to grab the `:id` across all actions. Place this at the top of your `transactions` controller:

```
before_filter :load_loan
```

And then after all the actions, add:

```
private
def load_loan
  @loan.find(params[:loan_id])
end
```

Use it like this in your `new` action:

```
@transaction = @loan.transactions.build
```